# SpTBX: make a button in Panel caption (near [x])

Tags: delphi, sptbxlib

I'm asked to add a btn near the `TSpTbxDockablePanel`'s [x] icon. Can I do it? Btn may look like this, note that wider button is better. (I need custom title or icon, and OnClick for it).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Items` property of dockable panel allows to add any items `TSpTbxItem` to caption. Can edit `Items` while in design mode.